# Load data only from test/resources while testing with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have an Spring Boot application integrated with Hibernate for the database persistence.

I have two different data.sql files:

- One in src/main/resources for database initialization
- One in src/test/resources for testing purposes

While testing, both of them are loaded before any test class. However, I only want to load the test/resources one, leaving the main/resources only and solely for app initialization.

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your Spring Boot annotations for main and testing?

Comment: @EstanislaoPérezNartallo the only annotation related to hibernate is spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
in both of them

Comment: @AlbertoCastaño Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` to `update` (it only updates the changes from the .sql file), because with create each time that the app runs, "cleans the DB", so thats why the both .sql are processed each time.

I hope this solve your problem.

Comment: No! Maybe I did not explain myself good enough. What I want is to actually create the database from scratch everytime I run my tests, but only from test/resources/data.sql, not from main/resources/data.sql. Right now both of them are being invoked

Comment: As @Rahul said, you can't stop loading the main/resources .sql file. Because is needed for the app to run.

Answer (score 0):

if test class is starting the spring boot application then i don`t think that you can stop loading the main/resources .sql file.

but if you want to load the .sql file from test/resources just before/after the execution of methods(in test class) then you can use @SqlGroup annotation.

```
@SqlGroup({
    @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:beforeTestRun.sql"),
    @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:afterTestRun.sql")

          })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following configuration (at least in spring boot 2) to your test application.yaml or application.properties file.

```
spring:
  datasource:
    data: data.sql
```

Once this value is set spring boot will only load the test data.sql when running tests.

Answer (score -1):

Maintain a separate properties file for test as it will help you in segregating the things between test and development.

```
application.properties for dev
application-local.properties for local env
application-test.properties for test
```

Have profiles according to your need and have properties with respect to profiles.

Another alternative is to override the properties based on your need.