# Spring Boot - Conditional Loading of Initial Data

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, junit, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have set up my Spring Boot application so that my H2 embedded database is populated at startup. I've done this by creating a data.sql file in the `src/main/resources` folder.

What I don't understand is what causes this to run at startup.

Also, I'd like to make this conditional - e.g. prevent it from executing when I'm running unit tests. Is this possible?

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51358189/820657), but it is unresolved.

Comment: Do you want to load data based on spring profile?

Comment: I don't know. I'm new to all this so still trying to figure it out.

Comment: quick and short explanation of how you can do it answered by me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040572/spring-boot-loading-initial-data/41644743#41644743

Comment: FUTURE READERS.. You can find a "spring profile" driven answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790743/spring-boot-execute-data-sql-in-one-profile-only/67941530#67941530

Answer (score 2):

The mechanism that causes your data.sql file to be loaded is described in the Spring documentation in chapter 85.3 [Database Initialization](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)

The data.sql file name is the fallback filename when no scripts are set through the property `spring.datasource.data` (for a list of common spring properties go [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) and look for properties regarding datasource)

So for your usecase rename you dml scripts to something like `data-default.sql` and `data-test.sql` and set them profile specific in your application.yml or properties file.

Comment: In addition I'd suggest to use high level DB migration utilities to set up your DB https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-use-a-higher-level-database-migration-tool